# Unable to update Windows OS

Tags: windows, operating-systems, software-update

I've been struggling to update my Windows computer since January of this year. I think I've tried updating my computer 8-10 times. However, every time, the progress percent reaches 90 something and then it says "We couldn't complete the updates. Undoing changes." After my computer finishes undoing the changes, it won't let me retry the update for a while. I really need a solution to this issue.

Comment: I provided an amendment to my answer for you to accommodate your small drive.

Comment: What version of windows? What sort of computer? What do the logs say?

Answer (score 0):

> I think I've tried updating my computer 8-10 times. However, every
> time, the progress percent reaches 90 something and then it says "We
> couldn't complete the updates. Undoing changes."

I assume Windows 10 (Windows 7 dead, not much Windows 8).

So run a Windows 10 (or 11) Repair Install and use the option to Keep Everything.

Go to the Media Creation Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

> Windows 10/11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair and proceed
> normally.
>
> At the appropriate time, accept the defaults for Keep Everything.

When done, Restart and your computer should have updated.

**Followup:**

Some of our comments have been deleted (normal), but you (@OP) did say that your drive was too small and would not let updates go through.

Two solutions (Similar):

(1) Get a larger drive to accommodate all your needs, back up and reinstall Windows. It will automatically activate with the new drive.

(2) Similar: Back up, reinstall just Windows and update it fully.  Now install just the Apps you need and restore just the data you need.

This may let you work with your smaller drive for a while longer.